# Maximal Interval of Existence Explanation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

$\frac{dx}{dt} =x^2$ with $x(0)=x_0$.

$x(t) = \frac{1} {x_0^{−1} −t}$ satisfies the differential equation above (provided that $x_0\neq 0$). Clearly when $t = 0$, we have $x(0) = x_0$.

Our solution has some interesting properties. If $x_0 > 0$ then the denominator is initially positive (at $t = 0$), but decreases as $t$ increases until it reaches zero at time $t = x^{−1}_0$ . This means that the solution, $x(t)$, has become infinite by the time $t = x^{−1}_ 0$; we say that it ‘blows up’ in a finite time.

Things are much nicer, though, if we want to see where our solution came from in the past. We can decrease $t$ (from zero) as much as we like, since as $t$ decreases the denominator becomes larger, and so the solution itself tends to zero as $t →−∞$. So when $x_0 >0$, we can define the solution of the differential equation on the interval $(−∞,x_0^{-1})$, but there is no way to define the solution on an interval that extends further into the future beyond the time $t = x^{−1}_ 0$ . We refer to $(−∞,x_0^{−1})$ maximal interval of existence for the differential equation.

I think this statement is completely wrong "but there is no way to define the solution on an interval that extends further into the future beyond the time $t = x^{−1}_ 0$". I think the solution is also defined even after $t = x^{−1}_ 0$ and here only $t = x^{−1}_ 0$ is discontinuity and it undefined at this point we can still get solution beyond $t = x^{−1}_ 0$.I have graphed the solution using positive $x_0$ and found that after $x^{-1}_0$ there are negative solution. So how am I wrong guys? I don't think book is right.We can go beyond $x_0^{-1}$ without touching $x_0^{-1}$.

Comment: Apologies for previously having rude comments due to Math rage.

Answer (score 2):

Look up your definition of solutions of a differential equation.

It will be something like: a differentiable function $x(t):I\to \mathbb{R}$ where $I$ is an interval, satisying the differential equation at each point $t\in I$.

In your case, if you extend the solution past $t=x_0^{-1}$ then either the function will not be differentiable everywhere (it's not in $t=x_0^{-1}$ as it blows up) or the domain of definition is not an interval. Thus it doesn't satisfy the definition.

The reason why we don't like solutions as being defined on disconnected domains is that you lose uniqueness unless you specify new conditions on each disconnected component.

For instance in your case, suppose you want to extend your solution $x(t)=\frac{1}{x_0^{-1}-t}$, defined for $t<x_0^{-1}$, past $t=x_0^{-1}$.

Then you get an infinite family of possible extensions, in the form $x_c(t)=\frac{1}{c-t}$  (for $t>x_0^{-1}$) where $c\in \mathbb{R}$ is completely arbitrary. They don't care at all about what happens before $t=x_0^{-1}$. Unless you specify $x(t)$ for some $t>x_0^{-1}$, you can't narrow it down to a single solution, which is what we expect with IVPs.

Comment: I was assuming that your solution was already defined for $t<x_0^{-1}$. So, if you want to extend it , by definition you can't change its values in that region.

Comment: I'm quoting your own words: "So when $x_0>0$, we can define the solution of the differential equation on the interval $(−∞,x_0^{-1})$"

Comment: And also why the solution is defined for $x_0=0$ doesn't it makes the solution undefined but book says it is defined and solution is $x(t)=0$ also $x_0=0$.

Comment: Sir first of all I think I don't  really understand  this one :"For instance in your case, suppose you want to extend your solution $x(t)=\frac{1}{x_0^{-1}-t}$, defined for $t<x_0^{-1}$, past $t=x_0^{-1}$.

Then you get an infinite family of possible extensions, in the form $x_c(t)=\frac{1}{c-t}$  (for $t>x_0^{-1}$) where $c\in \mathbb{R}$ is completely arbitrary. They don't care at all about what happens before $t=x_0^{-1}$. Unless you specify $x(t)$ for some $t>x_0^{-1}$, you can't narrow it down to a single solution, which is what we expect with IVPs."

Comment: I understand that the reason about the interval but that statement I really need more simpler version explanation. I really don't know how do I ask but really I don't understand it.

Comment: I think everything is conticting with each other ex you said they don't care about what happens before $t=x_0^{-1}$ but before you have assumed about the solution before $t=x_0^{-1}$. I hope you elaborate more in explaination. Thank you. I really didn't understand the solution of the differential equation too since it is contradicting if $x_0=0$ then solution is undefined and $x(t)=0$ really don't know how this comes from.